# Make Pending Announcement Viewed by Everyone

Tags: 2013, list, view, approval-process, content-approval

I need to create an Announcement List for News that everyone can contribute.

## My challenge is:

1. Communications Team will approve some articles to show on the Homepage (Parent Site).
2. But all pending articles will still show on their Team Site (Child Site).

Is this possible?

## For example:

1. A person posts an announcment and it automatically shows up on their Team Site so everyone can read it, but it does not show up on the homepage.
2. Communications team approves it to be on homepage and it exists on both.

Answer (score 2):

Set the **Draft Item Security** in the Announcement List in Child site to either "Any user who can read items " or "Only users who can edit items" while setting the versioning settings. This way users can see every announcement item in the child site. In the parent site set the logic for seeing Approved items only in a webpart like COntent Query Webpart.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, the logic for viewing news articles on the homepage of parent site will remain same as earlier i.e. to show only approved items using CQWP. However, for showing news articles in respective team sites, you can for example add a Choice column to the list which will hold Team Name for each item like Team A, Team B etc. Then in the homepage of each team site you will add a CQWP and put the Source of the CQWP to parent Announcements List. In the filter section you will filter based on the Team column. For information about how to use CQWP you can refer following link:
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2011/09/sharepoint-2010-content-query-webpart.html

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. I want to use only ONE Announcement List that resides in the parent site. Members of Team sites will be able to post to this List, but their news will only show on their Team site unless approved by Communications to show on the parent site. Does that make sense or is it even possible? I prefer not to create separate lists for all Team sites.

Comment: See the updated answer. Hope that helps.